# Can someone give me a roadmap or a routine to help me learn Blender?

Tags: modifiers, objects

I have been studying Blender on and off for a couple of months but I feel like I always hit a roadblock. I wanna start from the beginning(kind of). Can someone give me a routine they used to study or a roadmap which I can follow or just which concepts I should first(again)?

Comment: What you'd like to do using blender?

Comment: There are ample supply of free videos for beginners on the web site that has the name that rhymes with noonoob. Or you can provide optional support. Some series probably have 80 installments.  So you can follow their sequence or create you own within their offerings.  I read books all the time.  But with Blender I would recommend at least 75% videos.  Maybe a free book from a library.  Library may have free online access to Blender Training. Most books I have seen on Blender were out of date before printing.  Make sure to create simple Python drivers.  I would only entertain electronic books.

Comment: Of course you will run into roadblocks.  Blunder is a nightmare.  One random video selection ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccOk5JWg1Qg&ab_channel=BornCG

Comment: I mainly want to use it for simulations and modeling.

Comment: For modelling I'd suggest find something you're interested in the real world eg. any design object or even a special flower should help you stay motivated working on. If you're stuck right now, I recommend against practicing any fluid simulations since it's a lot of tech, research and not documented pretty well. Keep motivated!

Comment: Thank you. I willm I have been working on Fluid sims and based on your comment they are the most fun so Ill keep at them.